# What is the purpose of the parallel resistor at the end of this amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

I have this following circuit that I tried to decompose and find the purpose of each component.

The op amp is [LM6181](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/405/snos634c-522069.pdf) and the purpose of the circuit is to reduce the voltage of a probe so it fits within 0-10V for a LabView DAQ. Unfortunatly, the probe is custom made and I don't have any specifications on it.

From what I had,

1. Voltage divider formed with R1 and R2. The voltage after should be 8.35mV.
2. Why is there a 270Ω resistor before the AOP?
3. A non-inverting amplifier. Since R3=R4 the gain should be 2.
4. Why is there a 45Ω parallel resistor after the AOP?

From a simulation, the output voltage should be 46.66mV but when I measure it, it is more 8.4mV. Is it normal? Is everything after the voltage divider actually a matching impedance circuit with a gain of 1? Why do we have an input resistor before the AOP and why is there a resistor in parallel after the AOP?

[image: Voltage divider and amplifier circuit]

Comment: Can you say more about the origin and purpose of the circuit?  It might be that R5 is included to simulate the load that the circuit must drive.

Comment: Please add the actual opamp model you used in the real circuit.

Comment: The op amp is LM6181 and the purpose of the circuit is to reduce the voltage of a probe so it fits within 0-10V for a LabView DAQ. Unfortunatly, the probe is custom made and I don't have any specifications on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Voltage divider formed with R1 and R2. The voltage after should be 8.35mV.

Which is quite below the specs (1.7V), since a single supply is in use, and not too far from the input voltage offset (and even smaller than the worst case). By the way, the output would also not approach zero with this single supply:

[image]

> Why is there a 270Ω resistor before the AOP?

It could not be for input bias current (which is quite high) compensation since the value is very small and smaller than the parallel of the 2 resistors in the feedback (as opposed to what would be expected since the inverting input bias is a few times larger than the one at the non-inverting pin).

I wonder if it is not supposed to be a part of this compensation, with the capacitor missing:

[image]

The [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/405/snos634c-522069.pdf) recommends this instead of a capacitor in parallel with the feedback resistor. Not that it matters in this circuit anyway, since the \$270 \Omega\$ resistor is in series with the \$\approx 9.9 k\Omega\$ equivalent resistance of the voltage divider, which changes drastically the frequency response (maybe the reason for the capacitor removal). Additionally, this adds a DC error (\$39 mV\$) 10 times larger than the typical input offset voltage.

> Why is there a 45Ω parallel resistor after the AOP?

The comment suggesting it is simulating the typical load seems correct (although the smallest value for this resistance in some parameters and all the graphs is \$150 \Omega\$):

[image]

*Note: all images from the linked datasheet*

Further reading from TI about [Current Feedback Amplifiers](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa066/sloa066.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Most opamps cannot reach exact 0V at the output in a single supply context, there are some mV left, even on CMOS outputs. But if you connect a load, the opamp will not rise the voltage as long as it is the target voltage it would set itself. In a measurement circuit like this you want to see true 0V if there is no input voltage.

Answer (score 0):

As above, it is hard to say anything without knowing more about the context of the circuit.  But . . .

A trick to force an opamp output stage to be class A rather than class AB is to have a fixed resistor from the output to the negative rail.  However, the value of R5 is lower than usual for this.